# Entity Framework 6 mapping a custom SQL query to an Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework at the moment. I've been working with it for about 3 months at the current moment in time.

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application that's running Entity Framework 6. This is a code first approach from an existing database with auto migrations enabled so all of my Entity classes are auto generated. I am trying to add a view to my MVC application that returns a specific result set. Currently the previous developer has the application set up to only accept an Entity class to display data to a DataTable [DataTables.net](http://datatables.net). To clarify further:

I have two Entity tables in my model that are tables in MySQL.

```
| Samples           | SampleLocation |
|:------------------|---------------:|
| Id                |     LocationId |        
| DateAssigned      |           Name |      
| CheckedInDate     |           Size |         
| SampleLocationId  |                |        
| ...etc            |         ...etc |
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is querying both tables and returning the results to my MVC application in a view. From there run an Update and update a couple of columns in the Samples table. Below is the roughly the query that returns the results I need.

```
SELECT Samples.Id, samples.CheckedInDate, SampleLocation.Name, SampleLocation.Size, 
SampleLocation.LocationId 
FROM (Samples join SampleLocation 
ON ((Samples.SampleLocationId = SampleLocation.LocationId))) 
WHERE  isnull(samples.CheckedInDate) ORDER BY samples.Id
```

From the research that I have done there are a few ways to accomplish this. The ways that I've tried that would give me a class I could use are creating a stored procedure and then updating the model - this breaks the model and unmaps every single entity in the model. I have tried creating a view with the query to add to the model - but this breaks it as well and unmaps everything. I later found out that this is a bug.

So my question is, how can I map a query to an Entity that return results to a view? Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution to my problem. Basically manually creating an Entity within the XML and mapping it to a virtual table.[Entity Framework DefiningQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj730307(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish what you want to do, using either Entity Framework only or extra tools like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

**Entity Framework Only:**

First you can use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) to extract the data, I'll look something like this:

```
var list = from s in Samples
           join l in SampleLocations
               on s.Id equals l.LocationId
           where s.CheckedInDate == null
           select new
           {
                s.Id,
                s.CheckedInDate,
                l.Name,
                l.Size, 
                l.LocationId 
           };
```

**Dapper:**

The second method is using dapper, the only real difference here is that you would be working with your queries directly, so instead of linq you had something like this:

```
Connection.Query(@"SELECT Samples.Id, samples.CheckedInDate,  
                     SampleLocation.Name, SampleLocation.Size, 
                     SampleLocation.LocationId 
                   FROM Samples
                     join SampleLocation 
                       ON Samples.SampleLocationId = SampleLocation.LocationId
                   WHERE isnull(samples.CheckedInDate) ORDER BY samples.Id");
```

**For both:**

In your update method, you first have to retrieve the entities, for that you can use the `DbSet.Find` method or another query, after that you call `DbConext.SaveChanges`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My only issue is I need the results to populate the view from a class. The method that displays the results to a DataTable only accepts an Entity class. Unless there's another way around this?

Comment: In the EF one you only need replace the anonymous class with your entity class and for dapper replace the Query method with Query<Entity>

Comment: The way it is set up is it looks for a class from the Model in EF. If I just add a normal class outside the model it doesn't pick it up

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your issue, in my EF example, if you just want the return to be an specific type, then just replace the anonymous type with the one you want.

Comment: Roy - check my answer that I posted. This is what worked for me.